# Proving that an initial infinite ordinal is a limit ordinal

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

As in the title,

> An initial infinite ordinal is a limit ordinal.

How can I start proving that?

Comment: Start by writing down what "initial" and "limit" mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that there is a bijection between $\alpha$ and $\alpha+1$ for infinite ordinals $\alpha$.

Consider the case between $\omega$ and $\omega+1$, and see that it transfers to the other cases easily.